# Ember: Using itemController in ArrayController doesn't work (TypeError: Cannot call method 'lookup' of null )

Tags: ember.js

Following the examples on [Ember](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html) for setting the itemController in my ArrayController definition causes the blocking error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'lookup' of null
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgillick/M4BVV/

```
// Addresses array controller
App.AddressesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'address'
});

// Address object controller
App.AddressController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    city: function(){
        return "San Francisco";
    }.property()
});
```

The only way that I have found to fix this is either...

#### 1) Pass itemController in the #each handler ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgillick/M4BVV/5/)):

```
{{#each addresses itemController="address"}}
    <li>{{line1}}, {{city}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

...or...

#### 2) Add a container property to the ArrayController ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgillick/M4BVV/6/)):

```
var addresses = App.AddressesController.create({
    container: indexController.get('container'),
    content: [
        App.Address.create({'line1': '700 Hansen Wy'}),
        App.Address.create({'line1': '900 Hansen Wy'})
    ]
});
```

Both of these solutions feel hacky and very wrong. What am I doing wrong with setting itemController in the ArrayController itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `itemController` from the controller and the each view, don't have relation.
Although that do the same thing: wraps an object in a specified controller.

Your first implementation throws `Cannot call method 'lookup' of null`, because the `container` instance of the `AddressesController` is null. The container is setup when you create a controller by other container. This is abstracted for you, if you use:

```
this.controllerFor('addresses')
```

instead of

```
 App.AddressesController.create ...
```

So this work http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/GRaa5/

> 1) Pass itemController in the #each handler

Like I said before, `itemController` from controller, and each helper, don't have relation. So you can mix him.

```
{{#each addresses itemController="address"}}
    <li>{{line1}}, {{city}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

See this in action http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/spA9Q/

> 2) Add a container property to the ArrayController

This work because of the my previous explanation,

> because the `container` instance of the `AddressesController` is null

Finishing the @colymba example works, because before of the setupController:

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('content', model);
}
```

ember provide a controller in that hook using the `controllerFor`, then the container is present in the generated controller too.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the fiddle, it wasn't really the best way to go at it. Giving the code a quick clean up, I got this fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/colymba/kV8LM/

What I did is, add a route `AddressesRoute`, which `IndexRoute` redirects to:

```
App.Router.map(function() { 
  this.route("addresses");
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('addresses');
    }
});


App.AddressesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return [
            App.Address.create({'line1': '700 Hansen Wy'}),
            App.Address.create({'line1': '900 Hansen Wy'})
        ];
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model){
        controller.set('content', model);
    }
});
```

Using naming conventions helps, with the `AddressesRoute`, Ember instantiate automatically the Controller and the View.

Changing the View accordingly, its name to `addresses` and updating the `{{#each}}` to loop over `content`:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="addresses">
     <h2>Index Content:</h2>
    <p>
        Length: {{content.length}}
    </p>
    <ul>
    {{#each addresses in controller}}
        <li>{{line1}}, {{city}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

The `{{#each}}` loop could also just be written `{{#each controller}}` since it will look for `content` or `model` by default. In both cases, `controller` tells the View that it should access its Controller to find the content for the `{{#each}}` loop, otherwise the `itemController` isn't used (since it doesn't exist on the View). (which relates to what @intuitivepixel said)

The model and controller are the same as you had:

```
App.Address = Ember.Object.extend();

App.AddressController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    city: function(){
        return "San Francisco";
    }.property()
});

App.AddressesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'address'
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it's definitely cleaner. However, in our app, Addresses will be included in the Index template, along with a number of other models. Which is why we're setting it all up in setupController like that.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, that code seems a little bit weird to me, but anyways, the thing here is that you're creating a new instance of 'AddressesController' in the router, you need to change that to something like this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(indexController) {
    this.controllerFor('addresses').set('content', [App.Address.create({'line1': '700 Hansen Wy'}), App.Address.create({'line1': '900 Hansen Wy'})]);
    indexController.set('addresses', this.controllerFor('addresses'));
  }
})
```

Comment: btw, the error you're getting: TypeError: Cannot call method 'lookup' of null. it's right, controllers need a container, and the error is because you didn't specify a container, so, if for instance, you really want to create a new instance, then, your second option is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I originally had the same error when trying to instantiate `itemController` inside `ArrayController`. Although, my error was an outcome of clobbering the init method:

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    init: function() {
        console.log('i am USERS CONTROLLER');
    },
    itemController: 'user',
});
```

which I fixed by restoring default behaviours to the init method:

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        console.log('i am USERS CONTROLLER');
    },
    itemController: 'user',
});
```