# ember: linkTo object that has been elaborated

Tags: ember.js

Usually, when you build an index page you simply list your items in this way:

```
{{#each controller}}
  {{linkTo "lace" this}}
{{/each}}
```

But I need something more than a list. So I organized my content in a matrix, finding [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9JJa/10/):

So now i have something like this in my template:

```
{{#each row in matrix}}
  <tr>
    <td>
      {{row.key}}
    </td>
    {{#each cell in row}}
    <td>
      {{#each item in cell}}
        {{linkTo 'lace' item}}
        <br/>
      {{/each}}
      </td>
      {{/each}}
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

But unfortunately my js is failing with this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lookup' of null`

If i print my item, I get an ember object, so I can't understand why it's not working as it does as a normal list:

```
<App.Lace:ember722:61>
```

Comment: I would suggest to update your app to the latest release rc7, there where many changes made since pre2 which you are using...

Comment: done. I can't see any changes affecting my code

Comment: I meant also in your posted jsfiddle, so we can have a look

Comment: couldn't get it perfectly working but here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/FakrC/5/

Comment: You will need a lot of code to make the table, I recomend you to use ember table https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior it's a great project, but it's really difficult for me to understand it without a guide and with very outdated examples

Comment: Yes the guides isn't good. To learn I have used the examples in https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table/tree/master/examples. And you can see the examples running in http://addepar.github.io/ember-table/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember: Using itemController in ArrayController doesn't work (TypeError: Cannot call method 'lookup' of null )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194518/ember-using-itemcontroller-in-arraycontroller-doesnt-work-typeerror-cannot-c)